# Chrome margin or shadow overrides the top bar

Tags: google-chrome, gui

I'm using Dash to Panel on Ubuntu.

It seems Chrome in a maximized window generates a shadow or something that overlaps. It doesn't fully respect the margin of the top bar. It only happens with Chrome.

In the screenshots you can see the difference between other apps (i.e. Firefox) and Chrome.

With chrome:

[image: with chrome]

With others:

[image: with others]